# Why Isn't parseInt(str) Returning an Integer?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I'm working through freeCodeCamp's javascript introduction. Here is the prompt: Use parseInt() in the convertToInteger function so it converts the input string str into an integer, and returns it.

Here is what I have now.

```
function convertToInteger(str) {
var m = parseInt(str);
if (m!=Number) {
  return NaN;
}
  else {
    return m;}
}
convertToInteger("56");
```

convertToInteger("56") does not return 56. It does return a number, and a string of words does return NaN.

Nothing I have searched has worked (including specifying the radix and a variety of other options). Of all the solutions I've tried, this has the most correct when run, and there is no hint provided for this question.

What am I missing?

Comment: `m != Number` does not mean check to see if `m` contains a number. It checks to see if `m` is not equal to the `Number` constructor function, which it always will be.

Comment: `m!=Number` will always be true.  That isn't how you check the type of a variable.

Comment: `typeof m !== 'number'`

Comment: `parseInt` already returns `NaN` or the number for you, you don't need `m != Number`. Please see the return value in the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition:

```
if (m!=Number) {
```

will always be true. `parseInt` returns a `number`. `Number` is a function. `(some number) != (some function)` will aways be true.¹ If that was meant to be a type check, it would be `if (typeof m !== "number")` **but** again, `parseInt` always returns a number.

The number `parseInt` returns can be the `NaN` ("not a number") value, though, meaning that `parseInt` couldn't find *any* parseable digits at the beginning of the string. You can check whether it is by using the global `isNaN` function (or `Number.isNaN`). (You **can't** do it with `if (m === NaN)`, because `NaN` is weird and not equal to itself.)

---

¹ Unless someone specifically tries to make it false by overriding `valueOf` on the function to return a number:

```js
function foo() {
}
// Don't do this. :-)
foo.valueOf = function() {
 return 42;
};

console.log(42 != foo); // false
console.log(42 == foo); // true
```

The "will always be true" would be guaranteed if you used `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Thank you! That gave me exactly the information I needed.